# In Eclipse, is there an equivalent to Visual Studio's 'Watch'?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, ide

In VS, you can 'Watch' an object and drill down into it. Is there an equivalent when programming Java in Eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. If anyone else is searching for it, it's called [Expressions in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/expressions/ref-expressions_view.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the debug mode to watch objects, although it only works for local objects defined in the scope. I would recommend putting a breakpoint at the start of where you want to watch, and then stepping through the motions. In the top right corner of the debug profiler, you should be able to expand the tree of any given object that's in scope to examine it further.

The basics of how to use the debugger are [here](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html).